# Should I avoid running conduit above sewer line exit on basement wall?

Tags: electrical, wiring, basement, conduit, sewer

The prior owner of our house had an epoxy repair made on the basement wall where the sewer line exits (see images). We've lived here for 20 years and this repair is solid; there have never been any leaks.

Now I'm working on putting some outlets in the basement, and I'm wondering if I should avoid running conduit along this part of the wall above the exit point. Just in case there might ever be an issue in the future, I was thinking that having a conduit there could complicate a repair in that the electrical work would have to be undone before the wall repair could proceed. I'm not sure if I'm over thinking things, or if it is indeed a good practice to steer clear of this part of the wall, irregardless of the presence of a wall repair.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is that the water main next to the sewer pipe?  That can't be code.

Comment: Might give it an inverted U bend to **avoid being close to the pipes**, if the level you intend to run it at is close to the pipes. Personally I like to keep all basement outlets in the upper range of code "wall outlet" height at or below 5.5 feet from the floor - above 4 feet in any place you might lean plywood or other 4 foot wide sheet goods, and also generally in basements to reduce problems in the event of basement flooding.

Comment: @SteveWellens, that is indeed the water main. The house was built in 1964.

Comment: @Ecnerwal, there are only 2 original outlets in the basement, and they're about 3 1/2 feet from the ground. I figured I'd follow along with those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running conduit on that wall won't be a problem. Just avoid drilling your conduit supports in the area of the repair. You'll probably have multiple outlet boxes and outlets along that wall so in the rare circumstance that the wall needed major repair, you could remove a section of conduit between boxes. Good luck and stay safe out there.

Comment: That makes great sense, and somehow I hadn't thought of it. There will definitely be boxes on either side containing outlets. So, the wire can be disconnected from the devices and the conduit can be removed. And I definitely will avoid the repair area when drilling for one-holes.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't be a problem. Even if for some reason it was in the way for a future repair you could always cut the conduit do your repair and then patch conduit using a junction box.